# When does ASP.NET authentication occur?

Tags: asp.net, security, active-directory

I have an application where I display every Active Directory group that the current user belongs to.  When I have my config setup like this:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

It works fine.  When it's like this:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
        <!--<deny users="?"/>-->
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

No groups are found.  Why does this make a difference?  Does asp.net only authenticate if we are specifically denying access to unauthenticated users?

If it helps this is how i'm getting the groups:

```
    protected string GetUserGroups()
    {
        StringBuilder userGroups = new StringBuilder();
        ArrayList groupMembers = new ArrayList();
        DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myldap/DC=nc,DC=local");
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(root);
        ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(samaccountname={0})(objectClass=person))", User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1));
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberof");
        try
        {
            foreach (SearchResult sr in ds.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (string str in sr.Properties["memberof"])
                {
                    string str2 = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("=") + 1, str.IndexOf(",") - str.IndexOf("=") - 1);
                    groupMembers.Add(str2);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //ignore if any properties found in AD  
        }
        return String.Join("|", (string[])groupMembers.ToArray(typeof(string)));
    }
```

Comment: While I can't confirm or deny, it would seem like a reasonable optimisation not to authenticate users when no authentication is necessary.

Comment: Does User.Identity.Name have a value when it fails?

Comment: Asp.net doesn't require authentification if you allow anonymous access.
Really, why do I have to send my username if other user doesn't? Is he better than me?
You can put a breakpoint in the event of global.asax to assure of this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "why do I have to send my username if other user doesn't?" comment.  I don't care about user names and if a user belongs to any groups I'd like to know which ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I believe this is how it works:

The first time a browser hits a site it does so as anonymous.

If the server says that anonymous isn't allowed, the browser then sends the users windows credentials.

If those credentials don't pass muster, then the browser pops up the login box or (depending on the application) sends them over to a login page.

So, because your site allows anonymous, all of the users are coming in that way.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to force the browser to send the users window credentials?

Comment: @Abe: Turn off anonymous access through the IIS settings.  Just use the IIS manager.  It should be under Authentication (IIS 7).  Just disable "Anonymous Authentication" and enable "Basic Authentication" which should issue the login challenge.  IE will send those credentials automatically for the first test.  Not sure about other browsers.